# Changing values of a list by getting them from a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

So I have this list that looks like this:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']
```

so, a list with 2 elements

`lst =  [['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']]`

And then I have also a dictionary that I declared like this:

```
numberDict = dict()

numberDict["One"] = "First"
numberDict["Two"] = "Second"
numberDict["Three"] = "Third"
numberDict["Four"] = "Fourth"
numberDict["Five"] = "Fifth"
numberDict["Six"] = "Sixth"
numberDict["Seven"] = "Seventh"
```

My question: How can I get me list to look like this? To replace its values with the dictionary ones?

`lst =  [['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'], ['Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh']]`

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question but style tip: you can create your dict like `numberDict = {"One": "First", "Two": "Second", "Three": "Third"}` (etc) and save yourself a few keystrokes.

Comment: thnx man, yea thats shorter :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_list = [['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ['Five', 'Six', 'Seven']]
>>> [[numberDict.get(value, "") for value in lst] for lst in list_of_list]
[['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'], ['Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh']]
```

As an aside, note that you can also initialize the `numbersDict` in a single go

```
>>> numbers_dict = {"One": "First",
...     "Two": "Second",
...     "Three": "Third",
...     "Four": "Fourth",
...     "Five": "Fifth",
...     "Six": "Sixth",
...     "Seven": "Seventh"}
```